# Journal got blacklisted recently – how to withdraw the paper from the journal and database?

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers, withdraw, scopus

Recently, the journal where my paper was published got blacklisted in a so-called blacklist. I was very surprised since the journal existed more than ten years.

My questions:

1. How to drop the paper from the indexing databases, such as Scopus. What will be the consequences and what are the procedures?
2. If I will keep the paper in this journal, how it will affect my academic career?

Comment: Do you know why it has been blacklisted? The journal being blacklisted does not mean your paper is bad or wrong. I would not try to retrieve the paper, you have done nothing wrong. But since it might reduce your work visibility, you might want to add your article to an open archive.

Comment: What is this "so-called blacklist"? Who's in charge of it?

Comment: There are some called black-list databases. In this databases there are list of journals. The claim that the journal publishes a lot of papers. Silly, but if the journal period monthly, of course they will have high number of published papers.

Comment: You seem to have some trust in the validity of the journal ("existed more than ten years" and "very surprised"), but not in the "so-called" blacklist. If that is, in fact, the case, maybe you don't need to worry at all. Blacklisting can be (depending on the way selection is done) very opinionated. For many of the better cases of blacklists, the criteria are public and there often exists published reasoning for everything they put there, or at least the reasoning will be provided on request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you can or should "drop" the paper.  To paraphrase the jewelry slogan, a publication is forever.  You can't take it back just because you don't like the direction the journal has gone, or how people's  opinions of the journal have shifted.  Also, from a legal perspective, it's likely you signed a contract giving the journal the perpetual (and possibly exclusive) right to distribute your paper, and you might also have transferred copyright; so you can't legally prevent them from keeping your paper.

And indexing services are telling the truth when they list your paper as published there; you can't prevent them from sharing that fact.

One could argue a moral exception for a "predatory" journal which actively misled you about its standards and practices, in which case one could say your consent to publish was fraudulently obtained.  Even in that case, though, I don't see what you can practically do, since the journal is unlikely to agree to drop your paper.

How it will affect your career is unknowable - it depends on how important this paper is to your career, the opinions of the people evaluating you, why the journal was blacklisted, etc.

I think all you can do is resolve to be more careful when choosing publication venues in the future.

Comment: That's definitely reasonable answers. Regarding the career, it looks stupid, but people look if the journal is phishy or not. Yesterday I was sure to request to drop the paper, now I am rethinking again. Thank you, Nate!